# How to change radio icon on native-base

Tags: android, react-native, native-base

I want to change android radio selected icon style. But can't find the icon source, I cant just change the color and size but can't change the icon. I want this with "Check" icon.

I'm using native-base with material theme. And I export it for customizing.

Here's my Radio.js inside ../native-base-theme/components/Radio.js

```
import { Platform } from "react-native";

import variable from "./../variables/platform";

export default (variables = variable) => {
  const radioTheme = {
    justifyContent: 'center',
    alignItems: 'center',
    fontSize: 30,
    lineHeight: 20,
    ".selected": {
      "NativeBase.IconNB": {
        fontSize: 50,
        color: Platform.OS === "ios"
          ? variables.radioColor
          : variables.radioSelectedColorAndroid,
        lineHeight: Platform.OS === "ios" ? 20 : variables.radioBtnLineHeight,
        height: Platform.OS === "ios" ? 20 : undefined
      }
    },
    "NativeBase.IconNB": {
      fontSize: 50,
      color: Platform.OS === "ios" ? "transparent" : undefined,
      lineHeight: Platform.OS === "ios"
        ? undefined
        : variables.radioBtnLineHeight,
      fontSize: Platform.OS === "ios" ? undefined : variables.radioBtnSize
    }
  };

  return radioTheme;
};
```

And material.js file;

```
 // Radio Button
  get radioColor() {
    return "#7ED321";
  },
  radioBtnSize: 35,
  radioSelectedColorAndroid: "#7ED321",
  radioBtnLineHeight: 20,
  //radioColor: "#7ED321",
```

Comment: Changing radio button is not supported by NativeBase. But you can fork  NativeBase and change this here `native-base/src/basic/Radio.js`. Transpile after you change as NativeBase use dist folder as entry point.